# How to retrieve explode images path in database to view in codeigniter 2.2.6

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, explode

`hi guys am trying from 4 days am not getting . how to retrieve multiple images from using explode functionality.Now I need to explode that image in view . i getting single images from an array but not retrieveing multiple images in my database have  one row contains three images how to return result from model.
and show in the view file

[image]

[image]
myview file:

```
`<div class="carousel-inner" >   
     <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message')?>
         <?php   $item_class = 'active';

         foreach($newzw as $result){?>

      <div class="item <?php echo $item_class; ?> ">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
            <?php $img=explode(",",base_url().'uploads/images/'.$result->image); 

            //print_r($img);exit;

            ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $img[0] ?> "  alt="Los Angeles" style="height:662px;" > 
      </div> 
          <?php  $item_class = '';
                } ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->   
  </div> 
  </div>
```

my model code:

```
function uploadslide1()
{
        $this->db->select('*');     
         $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
        $query = $this->db->get("sg_slides");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
}
```

controller:

```
function index()
    {
        $data=$this->general();
        $data['newzw']=$this->public_model->uploadslide1(); 
        $data['body']="static/body";    
        $this->load->view('welcome',$data);
    }
```

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far? May be it can help us too.

Comment: hi anikt singh i just posted my code please help me just stuck there

Comment: and where is your view?? One more thing- Don't paste your code here in comments. Edit your question and update the code respectively...

Comment: hi ankit,  i just posted  the things please see above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just telling you how to using explode.

The `explode()` function breaks a string into an array. If you want to break your image value into an array format then you have to do this

```
explode(separator,string); // Syntax
```

In your case , plays a role of separator.

```
$img = explode(",", $result->image); //store image value as an array format in img
```

Now you have the `$img` variable as an array now you can perform itteration using `foreach`

example:

```
foreach($img as $src){
  echo '<img src="'.base_url().'uploads/images/'.trim($src)." />';
}
```

Comment: ankit meanwhile i getting 2nd images  not geeting 1st image in array[0]

Comment: ignore `foreach()` just var_dump your varibale `$img` to see how much items you have in your array.

Comment: kk ankit let me try

Comment: i just use another method ankit thanks a alot for you help .

Comment: @Iswaryaaone Show us how did you solve it. You can write an answer yourself.